# ASP.NET После компиляции настройки отличаются

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties

при запуске скомпилированного проекта настройки отличаются от тех, которые были при запуске из Visual studio.

в файле launchSetting.json

```
"ParchisLoginServerRelease": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production",
    "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
  },
  "applicationUrl": "http://192.168.1.111:5001"
}
```

в запущенном проекте из visual studio

[image: Изображение 1]

В запущенном скомпилированном проекте

[image: Изображение 2]

мне нужен проект с http а не https. а после компиляции открывается только https сайт.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: тут описано , что и зачем: https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/

Comment: Большое спасибо! Статья была полезна!